# how to use both form validation as well user id exists in codeIgniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

i use the following code for form validation and employee code already exists.i can easily validate the form but i am unable to display the message for if employee code already exist

as the following code for the controllers/employee.php

```
public function add_employee($site_id = false)
{

$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required|max_length[50]|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('father_name', 'Father Name', 'trim|required|max_length[50]|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('DOB', 'Date Of Birth', 'trim|required|max_length[50]|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile_no', 'Mobile Number', 'trim|required|min_length[10]|max_length[10]|integer|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email_id', 'Email Id', 'valid_email|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('e_code', 'Employee Code', 'trim|required|max_length[20]|xss_clean');

//$this->form_validation->set_rules('local_address', 'Local Address', 'trim|required|max_length[200]|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('permanent_address', 'Permanent Address', 'trim|required|max_length[200]|xss_clean');
//$this->form_validation->set_rules('adhaar_no', 'Adhaar Number', 'trim|required|min_length[12]|max_length[12]|xss_clean');
//$this->form_validation->set_rules('account_no', 'Account Number', 'trim|required|max_length[50]|xss_clean');

//$this->form_validation->set_rules('bank_name', 'Bank Name', 'trim|required|max_length[50]|xss_clean');
//$this->form_validation->set_rules('branch_name', 'Branch Name', 'trim|required|max_length[50]|xss_clean');
//$this->form_validation->set_rules('ifsc_code', 'IFSC Code', 'trim|required|max_length[50]|xss_clean');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('reference_by', 'Reference By', 'trim|required|max_length[50]|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('work_location', 'Work Location', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('designation', 'Designation', 'trim|required|max_length[50]|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('salary', 'Salary', 'trim|required|max_length[50]|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('joining_date', 'Joining Date', 'trim|required|max_length[50]|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('pan_no', 'Pan Number', 'trim|regex_match[/^([a-zA-Z]){5}([0-9]){4}([a-zA-Z]){1}?$/]|max_length[50]|xss_clean');
//$this->form_validation->set_rules('id_proof', 'ID Proof', 'trim|required|max_length[50]|xss_clean');
//$this->form_validation->set_rules('status', 'Status', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{

employee::add_employee_form();
}
else
{

$count=$this->employee_model->add_employee($_POST);

if($count>0)
{
employee::add_employee_form();  
}
else{
if(!$site_id) {
redirect(base_url().'employee'); } else {
redirect(base_url().'site_ho_view/'.$site_id);
}
}
}
}
```

and for the view/add_employee_form as below

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="box-register">

        <div class="panel panel-default">



            <div class="panel-heading">
                <i class="fa fa-external-link-square"></i>
                Employee details
            </div>


            <?php
            $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal');
            echo form_open_multipart('employee/add_employee', $attributes);?>
            <div class="panel-body">



                <?php echo form_error('name'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
                                                Name
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="hidden" name="confirmed" value="0">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>">
                </div>
                </div>




                <?php echo form_error('e_code'); ?>
                            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
                                                Employee Code
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="e_code" placeholder="Employee Code" value="<?php echo set_value('e_code'); ?>">
                </div>
                </div>

                <?php echo form_error('father_name'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
                                                Father Name
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="father_name" placeholder="Father Name" value="<?php echo set_value('father_name'); ?>">
                </div>
                </div>

                <?php echo form_error('DOB'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
                                                Date Of Birth
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker" name="DOB" placeholder="Date Of Birth" value="<?php echo set_value('DOB'); ?>" >


                </div>
                </div>

                <?php echo form_error('mobile_no'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
                                                Mobile No.
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile_no" placeholder="Mobile Number" value="<?php echo set_value('mobile_no'); ?>">
                </div>
                </div>

                <?php echo form_error('email_id'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
                                                Email ID
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email_id" placeholder="Email ID" value="<?php echo set_value('email_id'); ?>">
                </div>
                </div>


                <?php echo form_error('local_address'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
                                                Local Address
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="local_address" placeholder="Local Address" value="<?php echo set_value('local_address'); ?>">
                </div>
                </div>

                <?php echo form_error('permanent_address'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
                                                Permanent Address
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="permanent_address" placeholder="Permanent Address" value="<?php echo set_value('permanent_address'); ?>">
                </div>
                </div>

                <?php echo form_error('adhaar_no'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
                                                Adhaar No.
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="adhaar_no" placeholder="Adhaar No" value="<?php echo set_value('adhaar_no'); ?>">
                </div>
                </div>



                <?php echo form_error('bank_name'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
                                                Bank Name
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bank_name" placeholder="Bank Name" value="<?php echo set_value('bank_name'); ?>">
                </div>
                </div>

                <?php echo form_error('account_no'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
                                                Account No.
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="account_no" placeholder="Account No" value="<?php echo set_value('account_no'); ?>">
                </div>
                </div>

                <?php echo form_error('branch_name'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
                                                Branch Name
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">

                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="branch_name" placeholder="Branch Name" value="<?php echo set_value('branch_name'); ?>">
                </div>
                </div>

                <?php echo form_error('ifsc_code'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
                                                IFSC Code
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ifsc_code" placeholder="IFSC Code" value="<?php echo set_value('ifsc_code'); ?>">
                </div>
                </div>

                <?php echo form_error('reference_by'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
                                                Reference By
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="reference_by" placeholder="Reference By" value="<?php echo set_value('reference_by'); ?>">
                </div>
                </div>

                <?php echo form_error('work_location'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
                                                Work Location
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select id="form-field-select-1" class="form-control search-select" name='work_location' style="border:1px;">
                                            <option value="">Select Work Location</option>

                                            <?php foreach($all_construction_sites as $site)
                                            { ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $site['id']; ?>"



                                            <?php if(set_value('work_location') == $site['id']) { ?> selected <?php } ?>


                                            ><?php echo $site['name']; ?></option>
                                            <?php } ?>




                                        </select>
                               </div>
                               </div>

                <?php echo form_error('designation'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
                                                Designation
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="designation" placeholder="Designation" value="<?php echo set_value('designation'); ?>">
                </div>
                </div>

                <?php echo form_error('salary'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
                                                Salary
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="salary" placeholder="Salary" value="<?php echo set_value('salary'); ?>">
                </div>
                </div>

                <?php echo form_error('joining_date'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
                                                Joining Date
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="joining_date" id="datepicker2" placeholder="Joining Date" value="<?php echo set_value('joining_date'); ?>" readonly>
                </div>
                </div>

                <?php echo form_error('pan_no'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
                                                PAN No
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pan_no" placeholder="Pan Number" value="<?php echo set_value('pan_no'); ?>">
                </div>
                </div>

                <?php echo form_error('id_proof'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
                                                ID Proof
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id_proof" placeholder="ID Proof" value="<?php echo set_value('id_proof'); ?>">
                </div>
                </div>

                <?php echo form_error('status'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="form-field-3" >
                                                Status
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select id="form-field-select-1" name="status" class="form-control search-select" style="border:1px;">
                                            <option value="">Select Status</option>
                                            <option value="working"


                                            <?php if(set_value('status') == 'working') { ?> selected <?php } ?>


                                            >Working</option>
                                            <option value="on_leave"

                                            <?php if(set_value('status') == 'on_leave') { ?> selected <?php } ?>

                                            >On Leave</option>
                                            <option value="terminated"

                                            <?php if(set_value('status') == 'terminated') { ?> selected <?php } ?>

                                            >Terminated</option>
                                            <option value="retired"

                                            <?php if(set_value('status') == 'retired') { ?> selected <?php } ?>

                                            >Retired</option>



                                        </select>


                </div>
                </div>




                            </div>
        </div>
```

and the empmployee_model.php/add_employee as follow

```
function add_employee($data)
    {   
        $query = $this->db->get_where('spar_employee', array('e_code' => $data['e_code']
        ));

        $count = $query->num_rows();

       if($count>0)
       {


           return $count;

       }
       else{
        $data['created'] = date("Y-m-d");
        $data['last_user'] = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $this->db->insert('spar_employee', $data);
       }

    }
```

plz help me

Comment: It's been a while since I used CodeIgniter but there was a way to add a callback to this call - $this->form_validation->set_rules. In that callback you had to return TRUE or FALSE but you could set an error message within the callback. That message would be returned like the native CodeIgniter messages were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a rule to check if the value would be unique in a table.field. This is what I would do:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('e_code', 'Employee Code', 'trim|required|max_length[20]|xss_clean|is_unique[spar_employee.e_code]');
```

source: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference

Edit: as a note, you can also set a custom error message with the following:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'The value you provided in the %s field is not unique. It already exists for another employee.');
```